# How to retrieve values from a Data Extension on a Cloud page when a user navigates to it from a personalized email button

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, journeybuilder

On Sales cloud we have Contract records containing a checkbox. When this checkbox is checked, a Journey fires in Marketing Cloud. This journey will send an email to the email associated with the contract. In the email there will be a personalized button routing the user to a Cloud page.

[image]

The issue at hand is that I cannot get the data from the Journey Data Extension onto the cloud page.

The code is as follows:

```
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("Core","1.1.1");
try{
</script>
%%[
    VAR @contractId, @personContactId, @personFirstName, @personLastName
    SET @contractId = AttributeValue("Contract:Id")
    SET @personContactId = AttributeValue("Contract:Recipient_Account__r:PersonContactId")
    SET @personFirstName = AttributeValue("Contract:Recipient_Account__r:FirstName")
    SET @personLastName = AttributeValue("Contract:Recipient_Account__r:LastName")
]%%

<h1> 
@contractId: %%=v(@contractId)=%%, 
@personContactId: %%=v(@personContactId)=%%
@personFirstName: %%=v(@personFirstName)=%%, 
@personLastName: %%=v(@personLastName)=%% 
</h1>



<script runat="server">
}
catch(e) {
 Variable.SetValue("errorMessage", Stringify(e.message) + Stringify(e.description));
}
</script>
 
<script runat="client">
console.log(`@contractId: %%=v(@contractId)=%%`);
console.log(`@personContactId: %%=v(@personContactId)=%%`);
console.log(`@personFirstName: %%=v(@personFirstName)=%%`);
console.log(`@personLastName: %%=v(@personLastName)=%%`);
</script>
```

But these values come up empty in the HTML and console. I have done this before in a previous project, and found 1 more question regarding this, but for some reason I cannot figure out what I am missing.

Anyone any clue what to try or what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the issue was in the way button was configured to route the user to the Cloudpage. Our consultant initially configured it, so that it would link to a "Secure Website (https://)" with the url of the form directly inputted as Link URL.

I'm not sure whether that normally works at all, as I don't touch this part much, but the way I solved it was using `%%=CloudPagesURL(123,'ContractId',Contract:Id)=%%`, and then retrieve it using: `SET @contractId = QueryParameter('ContractId')` on the Cloudpage.

Weirdly, despite only the ContractId being explicitly defined in the url this way, all the other fields were suddenly being retrieved as well. This did not happen if I only used `%%=CloudPagesURL(123)=%%`, so I still feel I'm missing something. However it works, and if anyone else runs into this issue, check this part is configured correctly.